# AcquireTokenAsync only working in console app

Tags: c#, azure, token

I have created a console app that acquires an Azure token, and I can communicate with Graph API no problem.  When I use the same logic in a Windows or Web app, AcquireTokenAsync fails to get a token.  No exceptions are caught and a token is never successfully issued.  Below is my code that I use in both the Console app and the Windows app, but it only works on the console app. I ensured all dependencies are the same version.

```
        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string password)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, false);
        var cac = new ClientCredential(ClientId, password);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUrl, cac); //never issues on Windows app
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling this method, and the method that calls that method, etc? Are there any `async void` methods in the chain? Are you not awaiting something that you should?

Comment: I am calling this with: var token = GetAccessToken(password);  just as I am in the Console app.  No async voids in the chain.  Awaiting the AcquireToken

Comment: `var token` is a `Task`, not a string if you don't await the call or the returned `Task`.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed it to
                Task<AuthenticationResult> authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUrl, cac);
                authenticationResult.Wait();

                return authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;

Comment: Ouch. You need to do something like that in a console app, but you should not block with `Wait()` or `.Result` otherwise.

Comment: I'll brush up on Asynchronous programming. But your suggestion pointed me onto the right path. Thank you!

Comment: You can add an answer yourself if you found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was pointed onto the right path within the comments, and I don't really understand why but the following code solved the issue:

```
Task<AuthenticationResult> authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUrl, cac);
            authenticationResult.Wait();
            return authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: what's your graphUrl ?